# apt-get update non interactive

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I'm trying to make an update fully non interactive.(on ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)
I thought it will be easy with this type of command:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -q -y --force-yes && apt-get dist-upgrade -q -y --force-yes
```

but no... I always have a question like:

```
Configuration file '/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** cloud.cfg (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

So do you known how I can accept the default value automatically ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS/software tech support.

Comment: I think to ask how to make apt non-interactive is a valid question

Comment: We should finally sort out whether superuser.com is still needed or not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass some `dpkg` options to your commands, for instance:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get update && 
    apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade -q -y --force-yes &&
    apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade -q -y --force-yes
```

On a side note, I would recommend using *only* `dist-upgrade`, you will eventually end up with broken dependencies if you use `upgrade`.

Comment: For any other fellow travelers that find this, the quoting around `Dpkg::Options` is wrong.  it should be:  `apt-get -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold" dist-upgrade -y --force-yes`

Comment: For use within sudo, make sure to put the environment variable in front of the command rather than hoping sudo won't strip your envs, like:  `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold" dist-upgrade -y --force-yes`

Comment: @Irving, that quoting worked for me, perhaps something changed recently?

Comment: `W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.` (apt v1.1 and newer). Looks like the new equivalent is `--allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages`

Answer (score 14):

#### >= Apt 1.1

If you're using Apt 1.1 or above, [`--force-yes` has been deprecated](https://tracker.mender.io/browse/CFE-2360), so you've to use the options starting with `--allow` instead, e.g. `--allow-downgrades`, `--allow-remove-essential`, `--allow-change-held-packages`.

So the command is:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  apt-get \
  -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold \
  -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef \
  -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages
```

<sup>Note: Use `--force-confold` to keep old, and `--force-confnew` to keep new configs.</sup>

Source: [CFE-2360: Make apt_get package module version aware](https://github.com/cfengine/masterfiles/commit/f522dcd54482dffd99ccd690805a97f92216c0e6).

Related:

- [100% non-interactive Debian dist-upgrade](https://serverfault.com/q/48724/130437)
- [How do I ask apt-get to skip any interactive post-install configuration steps?](https://serverfault.com/q/227190/130437)
- [Non-interactive apt upgrade](https://superuser.com/q/1412054/87805)

Comment: I think you're missing the word "update" in your command someplace?

Comment: I still unfortunately get asked to select a drive when grub-efi is upgraded. Any ideas how to get it to select the first option by default?