# how can skip enter key pressing in script?

Tags: bash, apt, enter

I wrote this script to install pkgs one by one but some time have to press enter to continue.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read package
do
apt install ${package} -y 

clear
done < requirement.txt
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAiLW.png)

i want to skip this step!

Comment: Just ask apt to [install non-interactively](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556385/how-can-i-install-apt-packages-non-interactively) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update non interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370297/apt-get-update-non-interactive)